# How can I create a cron job to delete two files every 24 hours?

Tags: linux, vps, cron

I'm new at hosting my VPS on a CentOS linux server.

The following log files grow quite rapidly and I would like to have them **deleted every 24 hours**:

```
/home/httpd/tanguay.info/stats/tanguay.info-custom_log
/home/httpd/tanguay.info/stats/tanguay.info-error_log

/home/admin/__processed_stats/*
```

**What would be the steps for me to create a cron job that deletes all of these files every night at midnight?**

Comment: This question has been answered thouroughly by the community. Please accept an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not recommended to immediately purge logfiles as they may be needed later for debugging, statistics or tracing an intrusion. While log shipping offsite may be overkill in a single VPS scenario, there are better approaches than simply deleting those.

I suggest you look into logrotate or cronolog (Probably available as package on CentOS). With these packages you can set up rules how to process logfiles on a (usually) daily basis, like: Keep a week worth of logs, but compress all of them except today's.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that logrotate will work out-of-the-box for httpd as soon as you install the relevant package. I mostly stick with the default of rotate weekly, keep 4 weeks of logs - the possibility to look at month-old logs has been useful to me more than once.

Answer (score 3):

You can also reduce the information being sent to the logs.  You can set it to only log errors instead of information, warnings, and errors.  Just a suggestion.  If you want to delete the logs, make sure they are still not in use. Rotate your log files like everyone else has suggested.  They usually get compressed and deleted after a period of time.

Answer (score 2):

Logrotate is the best method.  In any case, you need to send the HUP signal to httpd afterwards, otherwise the filehandle for your log gets left open and your filesystem will fill up but won't be reflected in the sizes of the files.

Comment: +1 for the comment about open file handles. You could however use cronolog for apache logging, and then delete the previous days log as generated by cronolog without having to worry about file handles. Either way using cronolog over logrotate means that apache isn't restarted for log rotation, which is a good thing imo.

Answer (score 1):

To empty the files every day at 1AM you may use :

```
0 1 * * * :> /home/httpd/tanguay.info/stats/tanguay.info-custom_log
0 1 * * * :> /home/httpd/tanguay.info/stats/tanguay.info-error_log
0 1 * * * for i in `ls /home/admin/__processed_stats/`; do :> $i; done
```

But the good way is to use [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)

You may also want to take a look to : [log rotation tool that keeps only a specified amount of logs and discards everything else](https://serverfault.com/questions/42527/log-rotation-tool-that-keeps-only-a-specified-amount-of-logs-and-discards-everyth) and [Apache access log rotation](https://serverfault.com/questions/34387/apache-access-log-rotation)